# Web Scraping en c#

Tags: c#, scraping

Estoy intentando hacer un programa para obtener información de vuelos de paginas web y luego planeo usar esa información en una aplicación de escritorio, pero no consigo obtener nada de información. Estoy usando esto:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://www.despegar.com.mx/shop/flights/search/oneway/SAN/DUB/2020-06-01/1/0/0/NA/NA/NA/NA/?from=SB&di=1-0");

            foreach (var item in doc.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".fare main-fare-big"))
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += item.InnerHtml;
            }
```

Ya intente "acceder" a las distintas clases del codigo html de donde podria recoger lo que estoy buscando, pero no me regresa nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En principio quiero obtener eso, ¿Como puedo hacerlo? Estoy usando ScrapySharp

Comment: Para obtener lo que deseas primero necesitas saber dentro de que elemento se encuentra, si solo agregas la imagen no creo que sea de gran ayuda para saber como obtener el valor de ese elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes parsear esos datos porque la página los carga atacando una api, vía AJAX.

Este es el registro de peticiones que hace (obviamente hay muchas más, pero por simplificar)

[image: Ejemplo]

La primera línea es la petición que haces originalmente al navegador y es tipo 'document', eso te baja un html "básico", como un esqueleto sin precios ni información donde luego se van colocando los precios e información accediendo a la misma vía ajax.

A continuación se hace una petición 'xhr' (o AJAX, para entendernos), que es la que devuelve un JSON con los datos que necesitas.

Así que para buscar esos datos tendrías que llamar a esta url (o similar):

> https://www.despegar.com.mx/shop/flights-busquets/api/v1/web/search?adults=1&children=0&infants=0&limit=4&site=MX&channel=site&from=SAN&to=DUB&departureDate=2020-06-01&groupBy=default&orderBy=total_price_ascending&viewMode=CLUSTER&language=es_MX&airlineSummary=false&chargesDespegar=false&user=84e3ba57-0a07-4e16-8bf4-8ac693b545b1&h=d184eeded01f9a2c5d566f28f4500439&flow=SEARCH&di=1-0&clientType=WEB&disambiguationApplied=false&newDisambiguationService=true&initialOrigins=SAN&initialDestinations=DUB&pageViewId=1e3bb155-7053-4e7a-bfc5-c7f2ec0dc85d

Aunque ten en cuenta que si intentas usarla directametne, probablemente no puedas. Ya que habrá mecanismos de control como Tokens CSRF, referers, sesiones, cookies, etc. para garantizar que quién hace esa petición web es la página web y no otra persona.

Necesitarás inspeccionar bien la petición. Es probable que en la url "original"

```
https://www.despegar.com.mx/shop/flights/search/oneway/SAN/DUB/2020-06-01/1/0/0/NA/NA/NA/NA/?from=SB&di=1-0
```

venga algún token de mecanismo de control que luego tengas que usar en la siguiente petición de obtención de datos.